# PHP require once

Tags: php

I'm having a issue including `Auth.php`. The file is located at that exact position and that is the root of my WWW site.

No problems assigning the `$config` variable.

My code:

```php
<?php

include("./head.inc"); 

  // start a new session (required for Hybridauth)
  session_start(); 

  // change the following paths if necessary 
  $config   = dirname(__FILE__) . '/www.bommachine.co.uk/site/modules/ProcessHybridAuth/hybridauth/config.php';
  require_once("/www.bommachine.co.uk/site/modules/ProcessHybridAuth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
```

My error:

```
Compile Error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/www.bommachine.co.uk/site/modules/ProcessHybridAuth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') (line 11 of /var/www/www.bommachine.co.uk/site/templates/Test.php)
```

Not sure what is the best and safest why to resolve this.

Comment: don't you mean to do the same thing in your `require_once` call?

Comment: You don't use the $config var in `require_once`

Comment: It looks as if in the line you are assinging the config variable, you are prepending a path to '/wwww...', which would make it relative. in the second case, where you are using require_once, however, you are using '/www...' as an absolute path. So you might want to change it to require_once(dirname(_ _ FILE _ _).'/www....')

Comment: I don't think your site is located at the root of the server's file system, but that *is* where you're telling `require_once` to look.

Comment: I'm trying to load Auth.php, you can ignore config.php

Comment: let's `echo getcwd();`, so the script will try to found your path from that path.

Comment: Can you post the relative path of the file ? This might help us in identifying the problem.

Comment: Important hint: Never use any other extension as `.php` for your php files. There is a huge security risk there. If an attacker knows the url of the inc file (since it's inside your webroot) he can downloead it. And since it's no php, the webserver will return the source code, including any sensitive variables instead of trying to execute it and just return some empty page!

Comment: @ToBe It depends on the web server configuration. But if someone doesn't know about web servers, then you're absolutely right. <rant> It's also ridiculous to use any other extension </rant>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method that you're already using where you define `$config`. Specify a constant that contains the base directory:

```
define('BASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then use this where you need to require files:

```
require_once(BASEPATH . "/www.bommachine.co.uk/site/modules/ProcessHybridAuth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php");
```

But please, be aware that `__FILE__` will contain the full path to the file in which you are using this [Magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). If you use it in `/var/www/index.php` this will be the path. If you use it in `/var/www/subdir/file.php`, this will be the value of `__FILE__`.

Comment: There also is `__DIR__` since PHP version 5.3.0. Just use this and safe yourself some code ;)